# In R/list how to merge/rbind the sub dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, list

There is list `ori_list` , how combine sub dataframe `cat_a|cat_b` to `cat` and `item_a|item_b` to `item` ? (The result just as new_list )

```
cat_a <- data.frame(name=c('A','B','C'),amount=c(1,2,3))
cat_b <- data.frame(name=c('w','B','C'),amount=c(4,2,3))
item_a <- data.frame(name=c('z','o','C'),amount=c(3,4,1))
item_b <- data.frame(name=c('n','B','C'),amount=c(6,6,3))

files <- ls(pattern = 'cat|item') %>% purrr::set_names()

ori_list <- list(mget(files))

new_list <- list(cat= data.frame(name = c('A','B','C','w','B','C'),
                            amount = c(1,2,3,4,2,3)),
                 item = data.frame(name=c('z','o','C','n','B','C'),
                                   amount=c(3,4,1,6,6,3)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Note, that you were using `mget` wrong, it already yields a list.

```
ori_list <- mget(files)

list(cat=do.call('rbind', ori_list[grep('^cat', names(ori_list))]),
     item=do.call('rbind', ori_list[grep('^item', names(ori_list))]))
# $cat
#         name amount
# cat_a.1    A      1
# cat_a.2    B      2
# cat_a.3    C      3
# cat_b.1    w      4
# cat_b.2    B      2
# cat_b.3    C      3
# 
# $item
#          name amount
# item_a.1    z      3
# item_a.2    o      4
# item_a.3    C      1
# item_b.1    n      6
# item_b.2    B      6
# item_b.3    C      3
```

You could also do,

```
lapply(c('cat', 'item'), \(x) do.call('rbind', mget(ls(pattern=x, envir=.GlobalEnv), envir=.GlobalEnv))) |>
  setNames(c('cat', 'item'))
# $cat
#         name amount
# cat_a.1    A      1
# cat_a.2    B      2
# cat_a.3    C      3
# cat_b.1    w      4
# cat_b.2    B      2
# cat_b.3    C      3
# 
# $item
#          name amount
# item_a.1    z      3
# item_a.2    o      4
# item_a.3    C      1
# item_b.1    n      6
# item_b.2    B      6
# item_b.3    C      3
```

which might be better.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try `tapply` + `sub`

```
tapply(
    mget(files),
    sub("_.*", "", files),
    \(x) {
        do.call(rbind, x)
    }
)
```

which gives

```
$cat
        name amount
cat_a.1    A      1
cat_a.2    B      2
cat_a.3    C      3
cat_b.1    w      4
cat_b.2    B      2
cat_b.3    C      3

$item
         name amount
item_a.1    z      3
item_a.2    o      4
item_a.3    C      1
item_b.1    n      6
item_b.2    B      6
item_b.3    C      3
```

---

If you want cleaner row names of combined list, you can try

```
tapply(
    mget(files),
    sub("_.*", "", files),
    \(x) {
        `row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, x), NULL)
    }
)
```

or

```
tapply(
    mget(files),
    sub("_.*", "", files),
    \(x) {
        Reduce(rbind, x)
    }
)
```

so you will see

```
$cat
  name amount
1    A      1
2    B      2
3    C      3
4    w      4
5    B      2
6    C      3

$item
  name amount
1    z      3
2    o      4
3    C      1
4    n      6
5    B      6
6    C      3
```

Comment: Great answer. +1 Note that `Reduce` (instead of `do.call`) gets rids of the rownames, so might be a cleaner output

Comment: @Maël Thanks, that's good point of using `Reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are familiar with `tidyverse`,

```
ori_list_1[[1]] %>%  # (next line comment) combine all list. y is a list name and extract the chr before "_.
  purrr::imap_dfr(\(x, y) mutate(x, group_name = str_extract(y, "^.+(?=_)"))) %>% 
  split(.$group_name) %>%           # split by the group_name
  purrr::map(\(x) select(x, -group_name))  # delete group_name col.
```